# how to get key and sub values in to a format using php?

Tags: php

I have got data set like bellow

```
array(7) {
  ["Monday"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["count"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  ["Tuesday"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["count"]=>
    int(9)
  }
  ["Wednesday"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["count"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  ["Thursday"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["count"]=>
    int(5)
  }
  ["Friday"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["count"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  ["Saturday"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["count"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  ["Sunday"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["count"]=>
    int(3)
  }
}
```

i want to prepare this data according to bellow format.in there i want first print day and relevant count for that day

```
[Monday,0]
[Tuesday,9]
[Wednesday,2]
[Thursday,5]
```

I tried

> echo json_encode(array_keys($jsonData)
>   this print all the days.

this gives all the count.but i want to prepare data to given format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, where `$aInputArray` is the pointer/var to your array/data set above.

```
foreach ($aInputArray as $sKey => $aArray) {
    echo "[".$sKey.",".$aArray['count']."]";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($mainArr as $key=>$arr) {
    $newArr[$key] = $arr["count"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) encode $jsonData

2.)

```
foreach (array_keys($encodedJsonData) as $key)
{
   echo($key . " " . $encodedJsonData[$key]["count"]);
}
```

2.a.) or create a new array and fill it in the loop